# Merging 2 <svg> into one .SVG file

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a page where I have a button to export all the `<svg>` into one single .svg file.

The problem is that the code is only exporting one of the `<svg>`.

I can open it on inkscape, but only get one of the svg inside.

I can't open it on my browser, I get an error message.

I can't open on illustrator, I get an error message that the file is corrupted or something like that.

Here is the code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="svg-converter.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.svg-convert').svgConvert({
    onComplete: function() {
      exportSVG(document.getElementById('mySVG'));
    }
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#mySVG > svg{
  width: 40%;
 float: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <main id="content">
  <div id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/3000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <img src='https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/svg/leafers-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert'>
     <img src='https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/svg/aqualine-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert'>
  </div>
 </main><!-- #main -->
 <script>
   var exportSVG = function(svg) {
      // first create a clone of our svg node so we don't mess the original one
      var clone = svg.cloneNode(true);
      // parse the styles
      parseStyles(clone);
      // get the data
      var svgData = document.getElementById('mySVG').innerHTML;
      // here I'll just make a simple a with download attribute
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData.replace(/></g, '>\n\r<'));
      a.download = 'finalSVG.svg';
      a.innerHTML = 'download the .SVG file';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
    };
    var parseStyles = function(svg) {
      var styleSheets = [];
      var i;
      // get the stylesheets of the document (ownerDocument in case svg is in <iframe> or <object>)
      var docStyles = svg.ownerDocument.styleSheets;
      // transform the live StyleSheetList to an array to avoid endless loop
      for (i = 0; i < docStyles.length; i++) {
        styleSheets.push(docStyles[i]);
      }
      if (!styleSheets.length) {
        return;
      }
      var defs = svg.querySelector('defs') || document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'defs');
      if (!defs.parentNode) {
        svg.insertBefore(defs, svg.firstElementChild);
      }
      svg.matches = svg.matches || svg.webkitMatchesSelector || svg.mozMatchesSelector || svg.msMatchesSelector || svg.oMatchesSelector;
      // iterate through all document's stylesheets
      for (i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
        var currentStyle = styleSheets[i]
        var rules;
        try {
          rules = currentStyle.cssRules;
        } catch (e) {
          continue;
        }
        // create a new style element
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        // some stylesheets can't be accessed and will throw a security error
        var l = rules && rules.length;
        // iterate through each cssRules of this stylesheet
        for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
          // get the selector of this cssRules
          var selector = rules[j].selectorText;
          // probably an external stylesheet we can't access
          if (!selector) {
            continue;
          }
          // is it our svg node or one of its children ?
          if ((svg.matches && svg.matches(selector)) || svg.querySelector(selector)) {
            var cssText = rules[j].cssText;
           // append it to our <style> node
           style.innerHTML += cssText + '\n';
          }
        }
        // if we got some rules
        if (style.innerHTML) {
          // append the style node to the clone's defs
          defs.appendChild(style);
        }
      }
    };
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using SVG Convert (https://github.com/madebyshape/svg-convert) to convert from .SVG to `<svg>` before the page loads. That part works, no problem there.

Here you can see the code runing: http://brand.express/projects/teste/index4.php

Nesting the `<svg>` inside another `<svg>` doesn't work because they don't get nested. I don't know if its because of the svgConvert, but they simple are printed outside the 'father' `<svg>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the file available for download has two problems :

- it contains two `<svg>` tags side-by-side, which isn't valid SVG (nor XML)
- the `<svg>` tags have no namespace, while they should have a `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` namespace to respect the standards

The first problem must be worked out in your JS, while the second can be fixed by specifying the `svgCleanupAttr` option of your library call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.svg-convert').svgConvert({
    onComplete: function() {
      exportSVG(document.getElementById('mySVG'));
    },
    svgCleanupAttr: []
  });
});

var exportSVG = function(divContainer) {
  // first create a clone of our svg node so we don't mess the original one
  var svgContainer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
  $(divContainer).find("svg").clone().appendTo(svgContainer);
  // parse the styles
  //parseStyles(svgContainer); I didn't bother with it for now
  // get the data
  var svgData = svgContainer.outerHTML;
  // here I'll just make a simple a with download attribute
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);
  a.download = 'finalSVG.svg';
  a.innerHTML = 'download the .SVG file';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
};
```

You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/10dpo7rz/). I've removed the `parseStyle` function which wasn't needed here, add it back if necessary.

Note that the resulting svg isn't perfect, for some reason the root tag has no namespace. It was still correctly displayed by my Chrome.

Comment: The exported SVG donesn't load in the browser, I get the same erro.
On inkscape, I can open the SVG but it only shows 1 of the images.
On illustrator I can't open the file.

I have to find where is the problem and how to export the SVG with the proper code.

Comment: @MarceloHenriquesCortez yeah, looks like I should have tried my solution. I'm not familiar with SVG enough to have a solution at-hand, but I'm still pretty sure the problem is having two SVGs side-by-side in a file. After all, it's not even valid XML (since valid XML files must have a single root tag). I'll see if I can find a solution.

Comment: I know I can't use a <div> to contain the <svg>, but its the only thing I can use as a 'father' container. Looks like that with the svgconvert, the inner <svg> won't nest on a 'father' <svg>. That's my problem, I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: I think you could create a `<svg>` tag with the content of your `<div>`, let me try it out

Comment: I'm leaving work. But I'll check back as soon as I can and I'll run some tests myself.

Comment: Dude, you are a life saver. Ty so much.

Comment: @MarceloHenriquesCortez you're welcome. You should try to see if you can fix that root `svg` tag, ideally it should have an `xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` so that you don't have to declare a namespace on it two `svn` child nodes

Comment: will do. thnx again.

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution :D you have to group inside `<g>..</g>` for every svg and use `<g transform="translate(x,y)">` for next group

note: your second svg seem to be broken in Inkscape

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.svg-convert').svgConvert({
    onComplete: function() {
      // changed to css/jQuery selector
      exportSVG("#mySVG");
    }
  });
});

var exportSVG = function(svgWrapper) {
  // get the data
  var svgData = "";
  var vWidth = 0;
  var vHeight = 0;
  $(svgWrapper + " svg").each(function(i, v) {
    var viewBox = v.getAttribute('viewBox')
    if(svgData === "") {
      vWidth = parseInt(viewBox.match(/\d+ \d+ (\d+) \d+/)[1]);
      vHeight = parseInt(viewBox.match(/\d+ \d+ \d+ (\d+)/)[1]);

      svgData += '<g>' + v.innerHTML + '</g>';
    }
    else {
      var transform = parseInt(viewBox.match(/\d+ \d+ \d+ (\d+)/)[1]);
      vHeight = vHeight + transform;
      svgData += '<g transform="translate(0,' + transform + ')">' + v.innerHTML + '</g>';
    }
  })
  svgData = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + vWidth + '" height="' + vHeight + '" viewBox="0 0 ' + vWidth + ' ' + vHeight + '">' + svgData + '</svg>';
  //console.log(svgData)
  // here I'll just make a simple a with download attribute
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData.replace(/></g, '>\n\r<'));
  a.download = 'finalSVG.svg';
  a.innerHTML = 'download the .SVG file';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
};
```

```css
#mySVG>svg {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://brand.express/projects/teste/svg-converter.js"></script>

<main id="content">
  <div id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/3000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <img src='https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/svg/leafers-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert'>
    <img src='https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/svg/aqualine-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert'>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- #main -->
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense, and your code seems correct.
Now I can export the .SVG and open it in illustrator, but it only shows the second SVG (the blue guy), and the same happens when I open it in the browser. Can't test on inkscape right now.
I updated the testing link with the new code.

Comment: @Aaron found the problem. But you help me a lot in the proccess. Thank you =)

Comment: Aaron is not here haha... aaron solution is overlap and I was already found that since your first post, look here https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jjSn.jpg

Comment: Rly? oO The always got only 1 exported svg, and it never opened on illustrator =/
Only worked when I tried his code.
Sry =/