# Export style with <svg> to .svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have an HTML file, that has a link to export all the `<svg>` inside to one .SVG. That's perfect, it's what I need and the community helped me a lot.

Now I have a problem that all the SVG inside the file, are clogged on top of each other.

I need them to keep the same 'display' they have on the webpage. I tried using internal, inline and external style... But nothing worked.

The X and Y I have in the `<svg>` is executed when I open the .SVG file in any program, but it doesn't affect anything on the HTML document.

I'm using the svg-converter.js to get all the .svg inside the `<img>` and convert to `<svg>`.

For some reason, inside that JS, something don't let me group all the `<svg>` inside another `<svg>`, only inside `<div>`. I have no idea if that is somehow causing the problem of the style not being exported.

Here is the working [link](http://brand.express/projects/teste/).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Ps: I'd love to know why my question is downvoted.

Comment: I explained how to do this in [my answer when you asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45567887/1292848).  Use `x` and `y` attributes on your inner `<svg>` elements to change their position.

Comment: Some CSS properties (for example `float`) are for HTML only and don't work on SVG files.  You have to position them yourself.

Comment: Also, the fSVG file your code saves is not valid. It throws errors when loaded into a browser. Plus to be valid standalone file, the root `<svg>` element needs to have the attribute: `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`.

Comment: Remember, you can always [read the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html) if you want to learn more about how SVG files work.

Comment: I can open the SVG file on Illustrator, Inkscape and on the browser, no problem there.

As I explained I can't place the '<svg>'s inside a father '<svg>', only works when I use a '<div>. 

Not event if instead of converting to '<svg>' e convert them to '<g>'. 

Probably is something on the svt-converter.js that I'm not seeing.

I have no idea how to work with X and Y via CSS, since I need to use CSS to style the '<svg>'.

Comment: I am talking about in the saved SVG.

Comment: So am I. The only problem I have with the saved SVG is that all the images get 'cloged' together, that's what I'm trying to solve. But I can open and edit with no problems.

Comment: I get `This page contains the following errors: error on line 1 at column 15289: Attribute version redefined` on Chrome. I get `XML Parsing Error: duplicate attribute` in Firefox.

Comment: I worked with X and Y and it reflects on Illustrator and Inkscape, but there is no change in the HTML. I updated the question with that info and the new code.

Comment: For the final time. You cannot arrange elements within an SVG the way you do it in HTML. And you cannot use HTML elements like `<div>` in an SVG. So the file you save **has to be different from the HTML**. And you have to lay out the SVG contents in a different way (ie using x/y).

Comment: @MarceloHenriquesCortez If you have an answer, add it as an answer, please don't put the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS IS THE FINAL WORKING CODE:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/3000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://brand.express/projects/teste/svg-converter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main id="content">
      <div id="mySVG" style="width:100%;padding:0;margin:0;">
        <img src='img/leafers-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert' x="0" y="0" width="286px">
        <img src='img/aqualine-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert' x="286px" y="0" width="286px">
        <img src='img/leafers-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert' x="572px" y="0" width="286px">
        <img src='img/aqualine-sapling.svg' class='svg-convert' x="858px" y="0" width="286px">
      </div>
    </main>
    <script>
      //transforma os .svg para <svg>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.svg-convert').svgConvert({
          onComplete: function() {
            exportSVG(document.getElementById('mySVG'));
          },
          svgCleanupAttr: []
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script>
    
      var exportSVG = function(divContainer) {
      
        var svgContainer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "svg");
      
        svgContainer.setAttribute('width','1200px');
        $('#mySVG').find("svg").clone().appendTo(svgContainer);
       
        var svgData = svgContainer.outerHTML;
      
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);
        a.download = 'finalSVG.svg';
        a.innerHTML = 'download the .SVG file';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
      };
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `x` and `y` attributes to arrange your inner `<svg>` elements inside your root `<svg>` element.

Something like this (I've replaced the SVG contents with circles for brevity):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/3000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1224 1224">

  <svg x="0" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 612 612">
    <circle fill="#7AB344" cx="306" cy="306" r="250"/>
  </svg>
  <svg x="50%" y="0" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 612 612">
    <circle fill="#8DD4F0" cx="306" cy="306" r="250"/>
  </svg>
  <svg x="0" y="50%" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 612 612">
    <circle fill="orange" cx="306" cy="306" r="250"/>
  </svg>
  <svg x="50%" y="50%" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 612 612">
    <circle fill="rebeccapurple" cx="306" cy="306" r="250"/>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, but I dont have a parent `<svg>` and I'm not being able to do that. Everytime I try to do that, I get an empty `<svg>` and the the other `<svg>` outside it. The only way I got to make a parent was using a `<div>`

Comment: Huh? Your saved file **does** have a parent `<svg>`.

Comment: If you inspect the code, you will see that the page doesnt have one. Its made of 4 `<svg>` that are nested inside a `<div>`

Comment: Since the parent `<svg>` is generated only when I export, I don't know how to add that info to the exported parent `<svg>`

Comment: The error that was being generated was because of one of the `<svg>`. I changed the code to repeat the other two and the error is gone.

Comment: Something like `var childSVG = $('#mySVG').find("svg").clone().attr("x",posX).attr("y", posY).appendTo(svgContainer);` should do it.

Comment: Sorry for not answering before, my daughter was just born.
So, with the code you provided, it will only append stuff to the container `<svg>` it creates when I hit the 'export' button. I don't actually need that.
What I need now is to add attributes to the parent `<svg>` when its generated, to give it a width.
All the svg inside are displayed correctly when I open the exported .svg in Illustrator.

Comment: Just use `svgContainer.attr("width", "400px")` etc to add attributes to the root element.  And congratulations.

Comment: I tried that, but I always get an error msg: 'svgContainer.attr is not a function'

Comment: I tried in many ways. The last one I did is:

var svgContainer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "svg");

var svgContainer2 = svgContainer.attr("width", "400px");

Comment: Sorry, that should be either `$(svgContainer).attr(a,b)` or `svgContainer.setAttribute(a,b)` because `svgContainer` is not a jQuery object. It is a vanilla DOM object.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thnx a lot =)